# Different background image for different screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, background-image

I am trying to give different background images for different screen sizes. The background-image should be visible completely. I tried this solution [enter link description here](https://web.dev/optimize-css-background-images-with-media-queries/#:%7E:text=background%2Dposition%3A%20center%20center%20%3A,to%20cover%20the%20entire%20container) but it's not working out.
Firstly, how to give height property for different screen sizes and what are image sizes applied to mobile screen, tablet screen and desktop screen.

```css
.miracle {
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/Y0sWXBXs/Anti-Aging-1280x712.jpg);
}

/*--For mobile devices--*/
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .miracle {
        background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/T3Wr4hvq/Anti-Aging-768x600.jpg);
    }
}

/*-----For tablets: ---------------*/
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .miracle {
        background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/T3Wr4hvq/Anti-Aging-768x600.jpg);
    }
}

/*-----For desktop devices ------*/
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    .miracle {
        background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/Y0sWXBXs/Anti-Aging-1280x712.jpg);
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="miracle"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

For an article that is written in 2020 the approach does not make sense in a few ways. Not trying to talk bad about the author but here is the thing.

1.
You should have a mobile first thinking so your first `background-image` should be for mobile, so your first media query should be for the next size and so on,

example: keep in mind the first is mobile

```
.miracle {
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url();
}

/* next size - tablet */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .miracle {
    background-image: url();
  }
}

/* next size - tablet landscape and it covers desktop */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .miracle {
    background-image: url();
  }
}

/* next size - larger desktops */
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .miracle {
    background-image: url();
  }
}
```

as for the height it depends if `miracle` is your main container or it has a parent that controls the height. If it is your main you add heights to .miracle, two examples here.

```
.miracle {
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url();
  height: 280px;
}

/* next size - tablet */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .miracle {
    background-image: url();
    height: 380px;
  }
}
```

2. 

Use `object-fit` on the image tag instead of `background-image`. That way you can get the same effect as an background-image with the benefits of the image tag. My example also takes advantage of `srcset` meaning you can set all the images you want for breakpoints and the browser will take care of it. Browser support for `object-fit` is [great](https://caniuse.com/?search=object-fit), of cause IE is the problem, if you need the support for that, not to worry my example has polyfill that handles that (a javascript).

```js
if ("objectFit" in document.documentElement.style === false) {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll(".background-images");

    for (let image of images) {
        const parent = image.closest();
        const objectFitType = getComputedStyle(image).objectFit;

        if (parent !== null) {
            parent.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image.src})`;
            parent.style.backgroundSize = objectFitType;
            parent.classList.add("no-object-fit");
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #040A19;
}

.hero {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: #ededed;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 2rem;
    height: 40rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: .5rem solid #ffffff;
}

.hero__headline {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #090909;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.hero__images {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.use-content {
    padding: 2rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    background-color: #263749;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.use-content__headline {
    margin: 0 0 1.6rem 0;
}

.use-content__list {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
}

.use-content__list li {
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    
    &:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}

pre {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .25rem;
    margin: 0 .2rem;
    background-color: #0E1828;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero image-parent">
    <div class="hero__headline">Audi e-tron GT</div>
    <img class="hero__images background-images"
        sizes="(max-width: 2121px) 100vw, 2121px"
        srcset="
            https://source.unsplash.com/cpTecdXH3q8/600x700/ 600w,
            https://source.unsplash.com/cpTecdXH3q8/994x700/ 994w,
            https://source.unsplash.com/cpTecdXH3q8/1305x700/ 1305w,
            https://source.unsplash.com/cpTecdXH3q8/1569x700/ 1569w,
            https://source.unsplash.com/cpTecdXH3q8/1805x700/ 1805w,
            https://source.unsplash.com/cpTecdXH3q8/2038x700/ 2038w"
        src="https://source.unsplash.com/cpTecdXH3q8/1805x700/"
        alt="the awesome building">
</div>

<div class="use-content">
    <h2 class="use-content__headline">How it works</h2>
    <ul class="use-content__list">
        <li>Using <pre>srcset</pre> instead of divs</li>
        <li>Using <pre>object-fit: [type];</pre> so the image can act as <pre>background-image</pre></li>
        <li>Polyfill is a script that checkes if <pre>object-fit</pre> is supported, if not, it will take the image and place it on its parent as <pre>background-image</pre> with the same cover type as the image</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

3.
3.a: Use `srcset` on image, [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)
3.b: Use `picture`, [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give height:100%; for image like mentioned below,

```
html, body, .miracle {
    height: 100%;
}
```

if you check in this [reference example](https://web.dev/optimize-css-background-images-with-media-queries/#:%7E:text=background%2Dposition%3A%20center%20center%20%3A,to%20cover%20the%20entire%20container) they give us an example so you can check link

[Example](https://use-media-queries-optimized.glitch.me/)